# Flutter: On button press if slider's value is greater than 3 set it to 0

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

I'm using slider in my music app to display song playback progress. As a music player i'm using [Just Audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio). I use slider like this:

```
          Slider(
            activeColor: Colors.amber,
            inactiveColor: Colors.amberAccent,
            min: minValue,
            max: maxValue,
            // Change track when its ends
            value: (currentValue > maxValue)
                ? widget.changeTrack(true)
                : currentValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              currentValue = value;
              print(value);
              audioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: currentValue.round()));
            },
          ),
```

I added track change when slider's value reaches maxValue. Now i want to add different functionality. I have previous button that on press goes to previous song and i want to add additional functionality to that button. Basically, if its playing more than 3 seconds on previous button press i want to restart the music. Here what i have done:

```
                 IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    (currentValue > 3000.0)
                        ? setState(() {
                            currentValue = minValue;
                          })
                        : widget.changeTrack(false);
                  },
```

With this i succesfullty moved slider to minValue but its immediately returns to current value. How can i fix it?

Comment: " if its playing more than 3 seconds on previous button press i want to restart the music" - I don't really understand what do you try to achieve and how. Do you mean if someone is pressing the back button for 3 seconds restart music?

Comment: @stacktrace2234 I have a button. On press it changes song to previous. I want to add functionality to restart music if its been playing more than 3 seconds.

Comment: Your method `onChanged` might run right after you pressed the button, so your value `currentValue` is set to minValue but then it's back to the 'current' value from the onchanged method. Can you try to log it to confirm this ?